# Finding power factor of primary windings of a transformer

Tags: transformer, ac, high-voltage

A transformer rated at 250kVA with nominal voltage 20/0.4kV outputs 400V to a load with a power factor of 0.8.If the resistance of the primary windings is 15Ω , the reactance of the primary windings is 15Ω ,the resistance of the secondary windings is 0.1Ω and the reactance of the 0.05Ω determine the power factor of the primary windings.Core losses and core inductance are neglected

I used the equivalent model for a transformer while neglecting core current:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBFtfO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$a = \frac{V_{nomp}}{V_{nomsec}} = 20/0.4 = 50\$

\$ R_{T} =R_{pc}+a^{2}\cdot R_{sc}  =15+25 = 40\Omega \$

\$ X_{T} = X_{Lpc}+a^{2}\cdot X_{Lsc} = 15+12.5 = 27.5\Omega \$

Now the power factor will be equal to:\$ cos\phi =  \frac{40}{\sqrt{40^{2}+27.5^{2}}} = 25/48.5 = 0.51 \$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Your second line should be 15 + 250 and not 15 + 25.

Comment: @Andyaka Ah yes you are correct!